# I keep having my program crash here even though it's in try catch block

Tags: vb.net

```
            Try
                .Result = .WebClient.DownloadString(theEnchancedWinClient.PackedScannable)' crash here
            Catch ex As Exception
                LogEvents(ex.ToString)
            End Try
```

Basically, it crash because of a 503 error when downloading.

But that's stupid. It's  a try catch block. Why doesn't it just throw exception gracefully? What should I do?

Following the comment I turn the code into:

```
            Dim strResult = ""
            Dim webclient = .WebClient
            Try
                strResult = webclient.DownloadString(theEnchancedWinClient.PackedScannable)

            Catch ex As Exception
                LogEvents(ex.ToString)
            End Try
```

Still the program crash and stop there.

Comment: Looks like your using a `With` block, maybe it's crashing since the object is connected to a variable out of the Try/Catch scope. Change that and see if it still crashes.

Comment: Let me try then. I wonder how does that make the difference.

Comment: Is Visual Studio set to break on first-chance exceptions?

Comment: What does "it crash" mean? Does it happen only when running in the IDE, or also when running your app independently? (Your fix to "remove the `With` block doesn't work, BTW, because your local variable would end up just using the same `With` to do the assignment of `.WebClient`. Use the full name, as in `webclient := WhatEverFullClassInstanceItsFrom.WebClient` to fully remove the `With` from the equation.)